# Is there a way to convert an iOS app to a Mac OS X app?

Tags: iphone, macos, ios, app-store

Is there any way to port an existing iPhone app to a Mac OS X app?

Comment: Are you changing the GUI or do you just plan on showing it in a 480x320 window?

Comment: How the times have changed.  The exact inverse of this question was being asked two years ago, although I think the answers will be the same.

Comment: @ing0, haha, how do I find the apps he's made so I can blog all over them ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a very broad question and, as such, is very difficult to answer.

Generally the answer would have to be no.

For an app, if you strictly followed the MVC model, you'd be able to keep the model but would need to rewrite both the view and the controller. For a game it depends on how low-level it is. If you used a framework that it also available on the Mac then a lot may port automatically but you'll still need to reconsider the controls, screen size, etc. Either way it's non-trivial.

Comment: There is a way to port it. I call it the 'by hand-way.'

Comment: While the conceptual model may remain the same, a desktop computer has a vastly different interface than a phone, so a new UI is needed.  As Hockenberry would say: "IPHONE ITS NOT A FRICKEN MINATURE LAPTOP OK": http://www.viddler.com/explore/rentzsch/videos/26/

Comment: My app is very simple ! it has just some views , and the difficult part is a table view which is has plist data filled , each cell show specific text on detail view ...

Comment: Stephen Darlington your avatar is awesome! How did you get a Simpsons-style avatar of yourself? Is it possible to order it? I also would like one. :D

Comment: @es1 Ha, they used it to promote the Simpsons Movie. I don't think the site is still up.

Comment: I googled it and the best I could find is this service: http://cartoonstyle.com.pl/en/         I will try it. But thanks for the idea. Made my day! LOL

Comment: Apple added the `Catalyst` framework in `macOS 10.15` to let developers convert their `iPad` apps to Mac, but will that work for `iPhone` Apps?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while but looks like its now possible to port *some* iOS app over to the Mac. Obviously they will look as if they are running under the iOS Simulator, without the faux iPhone screen bezel.

The framework that makes this possible is [UMEKit](http://parsekit.com/umekit/), a re-implementation of UIKit on the Mac on top of Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt, iOS programming is view oriented with only one windows, MacOs instead is windows-oriented. Even if the APIs are really similar, the iOS framework is totally a new thing, recently projected (cfr. UITable).

Comment: It looks like then it would have to be a manual job of moving over what is common to the MacOS SDK and then finding other ways of displaying data for things like UITableViews?

Comment: My app is very simple ! it has just some views , and the difficult part is a table view which is has plist data filled , each cell show specific text on detail view ..

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the basic UI elements that iOS apps rely on (such as table views and navigation stacks) are not present on the MacOS.  So at the very least you will need to rethink and rewrite a lot of your UI, though a lot of the underlying application logic code can be reused.