# How to publish iOS Apps on Mac desktop

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, osx-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to convert an iOS app to a Mac OS X app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714063/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-ios-app-to-a-mac-os-x-app)

I want to publish my iPad & iPhone apps on Mac desktop too, is it possible to do, if yes so for that what changes I need to do in my code.

Comment: If you mean to develop for MAC OS X from iOS, here is a great answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714063/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-ios-app-to-a-mac-os-x-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS development is similar to Mac development but not the same: they use different GUI libraries (AppKit vs UIKit).

You could look into an open source solution such as [Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/), which is UIKit reimplemented for Mac. It has some limitations but is also surprisingly impressive!

Otherwise, as others have said, you'll be rewriting your GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can't do it directly, since iOS use `CocoaTouch` and classe like `UIButton`, `UITableView`, `UIViewController`, ... aren't available on OS X.

You can use most of you code which is do not use any of the `CocoaTouch` components since `Cocoa` is also Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

You may think it in MVC direction. Your modal could be reuse, while the view need to redefine. And of cause the controller could be a bit different since it is a bridge between View and Modal.

rckoenes explain in framework aspect. If you think in MVC aspect, I think it could be easier to understand.

I hope it help. Thanks

Comment: Not true, although maybe not drastically (depending on the code), changes will have to be made all across the MVC board.